# How to get a visa for Qatar when holding a visa invitation letter?

Tags: visas, egypt, qatar

I'm staying in Egypt and I have a tourist visa for Qatar (just a paper) sent to me by a family member. I was wondering, should I still go to a Qatar Embassy here in Egypt to get it stamped? Or is the visa paper that was sent to me is enough? I was wondering because I know before leaving Philippines Filipino's should get their visa's stamped first at the embassy to get an official visa sticker. I was wondering if it's the same for Filipinos living abroad?

Comment: Do you have a photo of the visa?

Comment: Did you provide him with passport photocopy ?

Answer (score 3):

Considering you are a Filipino living in Egypt; you will need

- valid visa prior to travel
- passport validity of more than 6 months

you cannot get an on arrival visa for Qatar. Since you have a tourist visa; if it is the original visa paper it should have the same details mentioned on your passport and you can travel with it. you will have to show the original visa paper to the airline and immigration counters in Egypt. Your passport will get a tourist visa stamp once you reach Qatar immigration.

If the visa paper you have is a copy (not the original) then you may need to get an "ok to board". Please contact the airline helpdesk on how to get that.

For what I have seen for the middle east, its ok to travel with the "original" visa. It doesn't have to be stamped on your passport. Only the visas you apply at an embassy are stamped on your passport. Visas which are obtained by sponsors are  just like your scenario.